# Convergence of spheres in nonlinear stability of Minkowski space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, general-relativity

My question is about Lemma 3.3.1 in Christodoulou and Klainerman's proof of nonlinear stability of Minkowski space. This lemma says the following: Consider a family of metrics $m_u$ on $S^2$ defined for $u \in (u_0, \infty)$. Define $m_\infty$ to be the standard unit round metric on $S^2$. Let $K(u)$ be the Gaussian curvature of $(S^2, m_u)$, and suppose that $K(u) \to 1$ as $u \to \infty$. Then, under some additional finiteness assumptions on integrals of various geometric quantities, the eigenvalues $\lambda(u) \leq \Lambda(u)$ of $m_u$ relative to $m_\infty$ converge to 1 as $u \to \infty$.

My question is specifically going from line 3.3.5b:
$$
\partial_u \mu(u) = a r^{-1}\kappa\mu
$$
(all functions here are some real-valued functions of $u$) to line 3.3.5c:
$$
\mu(u) = \exp(-\int_u^\infty a r^{-1}\kappa).
$$
The argument is just to integrate the previous line. However, it seems to me that the "initial" condition at infinty - which is assumed to be 1 in line 3.3.5c - is (similar to) what we want to be proving. I'm not sure exactly what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way to understand the argument is this: fix an arbitrary frame (not necessarily orthogonal) on $S^2$. Then equation 3.3.5a should still hold (it should hold for any frame that is fermi transported). By equation 3.3.1 you can integrate the RHS so that a limiting metric $m_\infty$ exists. For this limiting metric, the author then proves that convergence is uniform. Then they also prove that the Christoffel symbols converge uniformly. And earlier on the Gaussian curvature also converges. So the limiting Gaussian curvature is equal to the Gaussian curvature of the limiting metric and so the $m_\infty$ metric must be round.

(No, this is not how the proof is written in the book; but that's how I understand what is going on.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think my remaining worry comes down to calculus fact of $f_n \to f$ not implying $f_n' \to f'$ without additional assumptions. Is the convergence of the Gaussian curvature enough to ensure that the Christoffel symbol convergence holds at the level of its derivatives as well? Gaussian curvature is some combination of derivatives of Christoffel symbols, so I wasn't sure if assuming its convergence was enough to give us the extra assumption needed. (For instance there could be some cancellation?)

Comment: Morally speaking, Gaussian curvature is "elliptic" of the metric, and so you should have enough bounds to ensure that the limiting metric is at least $C^{1,1-\epsilon}$, and then the uniqueness of the round metric can still be used. But admittedly I am not sure how to fill in all the details right now.